# How to add my plugin to Processing?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I made a new plugin for QGIS and I want to include it to the Processing toolbar. I can't find a good hint on how to do it cleanly (applying answer of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/83466/12768) on my algorithms seems dirty). So, how to do it?

I built the plugin using Plugin Builder and I already published it (FYI, it's [this one](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/fft-convolution-filter-master/)). However, I would like to enable processing-specific options like using batch.

Comment: @Underdark asked something similar a few years ago, back when _Processing_ was called _Sextante_. Perhaps the workflow is still valid? [Expanding Sextante’s ftools toolbox](http://anitagraser.com/2012/12/11/expanding-sextantes-ftools-toolbox/).

Comment: I've been pointed to LecoS as an example of a plugin available in the processing. Its processing/sextante wrapper is [here](https://github.com/Martin-Jung/LecoS/blob/master/lecos_sextanteprov.py). I would prefer someone more proficient to explain it here, but I might as well try to reverse engineer it and answer myself tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this example instead of LecoS. It will be easier for you to understand how to write down a new provider for Processing

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/exampleprovider